# Create a matrix from a table?

Tags: excel, matrix

I have a file with a table of rows like this

> i,j,x

and I would like to convert it to a matrix from i to j having the x values, which represent the flow between i and j. 
The problem consists of the absence of all i's and j's numbers.

I tried with a pivot table, but the result is this:

***Pivot matrix***

[image]

So, I would like to have j={1,...n} columns and i={1,...n} rows.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your original data as well plz? And what the output should look like?